# "Next Quote" Button unable to work

Tags: jquery

I need some advice on my issue with my "Next Quote" button.

Here is the part of the code that I think is where the problem is `$("#newQuote").on("click", function(){getQuote();});`

You can find my code at https://codepen.io/ChaosSaveren29/pen/vZPYez.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your issue is with `id='#nextQuote'` don't include the `#` in the id

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please take time to read the [tour] and [ask].  Also have a look at [mcve].

Comment: From the vote page:  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.* Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Hi, guys, thanks for your advise, it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put # in the id attribute of your HTML element.

As an example, this will work.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id='nextQuote'>Next Quote</button>
```

Elaboration Edit:
JQuery uses # in front of your element name to point it to ID attribute and . to point a class attribute. I think you got mixed up. You shouldn't actually put the hash into your attribute just like you wouldn't put a dot into your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Button ID is wrong. You shouldn't use special char like `#` in element attributes

change `id` from

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id='#nextQuote'>Next Quote</button>
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id='nextQuote'>Next Quote</button>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use but some special char you need to avoid